# Showing notifications on Windows 10 with Python

Tags: python, windows, notifications

I'm using win10toaster library. I'm using this example code, first time worked but now doesn't show any notification. No erros on console.

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast(
        "Hello World!!!",
        "Python is 10 seconds awsm!",
        duration=10)
    toaster.show_toast(
        "Example two",
        "Once you start coding in Python you'll hate other languages")
```

This is what I'm running on CMD:

```
>>> from win10toast import ToastNotifier
>>> toaster = ToastNotifier()
>>> toaster.show_toast("Test title", "Test message", duration=10)
True
```

And no notification appears, only an icon on toolbar

**EDIT**

I have test the code in other computer with Windows Server 2012 and it show notifications.

Comment: How do you run script ?

Comment: Windows console @DinkoPehar

Comment: @PiterMcFlebor I just tested it on my windows10 a few times and it works well. I think that in your case the problem must come from your system and not from the code. Did you check in your settings that the notification option is turned on?